# How to aggregate arrays that contains an id?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Imagine the following collection on mongodb:

```
{ id: 1, array1: [ObjectId("1001"), ObjectId("1002")], 
         array2: [ObjectId("1003"), ObjectId("1004")] }
{ id: 2, array1: [ObjectId("1001"), ObjectId("1004")], 
         array2: [ObjectId("1002")] }
{ id: 3, array1: [ObjectId("1003"), ObjectId("1004")], 
         array2: [ObjectId("1005")] }
{ id: 4 }
```

Now I want to create a projection like this:

```
db.coll.aggregate([{ $project: 
     { setInAnyArray: { ObjectId("1002") : { $in: ["$array1", "$array2"] }}}
}]);
```

the result should be like:

```
{ id: 1, setInAnyArray: true }
{ id: 2, setInAnyArray: true }
{ id: 3, setInAnyArray: false }
{ id: 4, setInAnyArray: false }
```

how would you solve this? thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method.

You need to [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) your documents and using the [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/#exp._S_setUnion) which returns a set with elements that appear in any of your array. Also you need the [`$setIsSubet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/#exp._S_setIsSubset) because the `$in` is not allow in the `$project` stage. Last but not least you should use the [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator to set default value for documents where those fields are absent if not your query will miserably fail.

```js
db.coll.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "id": 1, 
        "_id": 0, 
        "setInAnyArray": { 
            "$setIsSubset": [
                [1002], 
                { "$setUnion": [ 
                    { "$ifNull": [ "$array1", [false] ] }, 
                    { "$ifNull": [ "$array2", [true] ] }
                ] }
            ] 
        }
    }}
])
```